# Grails HttpSecurity - allowing POST

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

I have a rather simple security config in my Grails 3.0.3 application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers('/admin/**').hasAnyRole('ADMIN')
            .antMatchers('/**').hasAnyRole('USER', 'ADMIN')
            //.antMatchers('/').permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll()

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable()

    http.csrf().disable()
}
```

I have also some DomainClasses which use @Resource annotation

```
@Resource(uri="/myresource",formats=['json'])
```

When I turn off authentication for /** path - everything works fine. But when I leave authentication for /** on, so including /myresource, it no longer accepts POST requests. It returns 405 method not allowed then. 
How can I allow POST requests using HttpSecurity in Grails 3?

UPDATE 1:
GET requests are allowed for authenticated users

Comment: Hello Piotr Do you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran into the same problem. There are two ways to solve it:

1. disable csrf protection by `HttpSecurity http.csrf().disable()` in
   configure method
2. add a csrf token to your JSON. More about this you could read at
   [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html).

Comment: I already have csrf disabled - see the code snippet in the question.